# BFS and DFS by using adjacency matrix C#

Tags: c#, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

How to implement BFS (Breadth First Search) and DFS (Depth First Search) using an adjacency matrix if the vertices in the graph are specified in string format (not integer)? Available code: https://github.com/surbacim/graph-c-/blob/main/graph

Comment: Store the vertices in a vector and use the index numbers in the search code.

Comment: @ravenspoint I need exactly using adjacency matrix, no vectors

Comment: Read the the data from the matrix to populate the vector, then use the vector in the standard search code.

Comment: @ravenspoint Sorry, but it is possible to do it using only the adjacency matrix? :) Like
public static void BFS (int [,]adj, Vertice start)
{
...
 if (adj [start] [i] == 1 && (! Visited [i])) {
DFS (i, visited);
...
}

Comment: I suppose it may be, but why bother?  A simple transformation of your data gives you access to tested and high performance code.  Brewing your own code to pick away at an awkward data structure will be time consuming, error prone and the result will have poor performance.  You are barking up the wrong tree.